# Error 1064 in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1064

Why does the following show a mysql 1064 error?

I have a the following table:

```
daily_note (id, time (timestamp), rate_id, note )
```

On this table I'm executing the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO daily_note (note)
VALUES ('this is a note')
WHERE rate_id = 37
AND time > '2011-05-22 00:00:00'
```

**Cannot perform insert:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE rate_id = 37 AND time > '2011-05-22 00:' at line 3'

Answer (score 1):

You can't INSERT using a WHERE statement.  If you want to modify existing records based on some condition/criteria, use an UPDATE statement instead of INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` with `WHERE` makes no sense.

`INSERT` creates new rows, whereas `WHERE` specifies criteria for retrieving/updating existing rows.

Read up about [the syntax and meaning of the statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) that you're trying to use, before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Code should read:

```
UPDATE DAILY_NOTE
SET field='this is a not'
WHERE rate_id = 37
AND time > '2011-05-22 00:00:00'
```